# hidden symbol `__cxa_begin_cleanup'

Tags: android, hyperlink

In attempting to compile a special blend of sqlite3 for Android, I ran into following

> /Volumes/Projects/api9-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   .libs/sqlite3: hidden symbol `__cxa_begin_cleanup' in
>   /Volumes/Projects/api9-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/libstdc++.a(eh_arm.o)
>   is referenced by DSO
>   /Volumes/Projects/api9-arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
>   final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

What does this mean? What is a hidden symbol? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

check your version of NDK that is installed and update it to the Latest available